# Sins are made/done?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, collocations, word-in-context

I'm trying to find a right word to use. Are sins made or done, maybe created? I know that I can say: 'he sinned' but i want to have the noun.

- He (made) a sin when he killed that woman.

Please help.

Comment: He **committed** sin.

Comment: Either "He sinned when he killed that woman." or "He committed a sin when he killed that woman" are grammatical sentences.

Comment: I suggest you use Longman Dictionaries for collocations or Oxford Learners Dictionary.. There can  many collocations associated with a word..So it would save time.Here is the link http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You neither make nor do a sin.  Instead, you sin or commit a sin.

> He committed a sin when he killed that woman
>
> He committed the sin of killing that woman.
>
> He sinned when he killed that woman.

Comment: Alright. I'll use commit!